# Cannot get the exact bash prompt I want

Tags: bash

What's throwing me off mostly is trying to get new lines as I want. And trust me, I've googled and searched through this site, but can't get exactly what I want. I either get parsing errors or not exactly what I want.

What I want is this

```
/c/what/ever/folder/here
(gitbranch)
$ STARTTYPING HERE
```

first line green, second yellow, third white.  What I've been able to come up with gives me this:

```
/c/what/ever/folder/here
 (gitbranch) $ STARTTYPING HERE
```

note the extra space before (gitbranch) and lack of newline before the "$"

here is my PS1 so far:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\n\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

I'm wanting this because we sometimes have long branch and directory names and hate having my prompt start anywhere but to the far left

Comment: I don't see any `\n` before `$`

Comment: bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `parse_git_branch)'
~

$

if I do that

Comment: What happens if you try `\w\n\[...`

Comment: directory, blank line, gitbranch+$

Comment: OK, so get rid of your escapes, try: `\[\033[32m\]\w\n\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\n\[\033[00m\]$ `

Comment: same syntax error as before

Comment: git branch goes away

Comment: Using double quotes makes your assignment really unnecessarily complicated. If you used single quotes, you'd need fewer backslashes. (That said, this isn't really a StackOverflow question -- writing scripts is very much on-topic here, but this is more a matter of environment configuration that isn't software-development-specific in any substantive way, and thus a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think involving `sed` is generating some output that is really confusing the expansions inside the double-quoted string you're using for `PS1`.

You could switch to splicing special strings, single-quoted strings, and double quoted ones together (e.g. `"$foo"'"not $expanded'$'\n'`) if you like, but that's a bit confusing.

Instead, why not skip parsing `git branch`'s output at all, and just ask for the branch directly?

Assuming that you want the branch name (second line) not to show up *at all* when not in a Git repository, this works:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)
PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w${branch:+\[\033[33m\]\n($branch)}\[\033[00m\]\n$ "
```

The magic is in the `:+` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) statement: it assigns/returns everything on the right of the plus if the left side is non-empty; nothing otherwise. Think of it a bit like the `$cond ? $trueval : $falseval` ternary operator in other programming languages.

If you want a default string instead of no second line, try:

```
PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\n(${branch:-no branch detected})\[\033[00m\]\n$ "
```

When you're in a brand new repo, but you haven't committed anything yet, that code will prompt that you're in branch `HEAD`. If you'd like it to say `master` or something else, do something like this:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)
if [ "$branch" = "HEAD" ]; then
    branch="master, brand new"
fi
```

You're probably already doing this, but if you want your prompt to update when you change directories, running that code once won't work; it'll "stick" with whatever the git branch of where you first ran it was. To make that happen, plug that code into your `PROMPT_COMMAND` bash variable via a function, like so:

```
prompt_with_git() {
    branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)
    PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w${branch:+\[\033[33m\]\n($branch)}\[\033[00m\]\n$ "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_with_git
```

Once you've `source`d that, things should work.

Note that this requires a Git that supports the `rev-parse` command and arguments used here. Do `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` in a committed repo folder manually to check if yours does; if there's an error, you may need to upgrade your Git.

Comment: almost there. The git branch isn't showing up when in a git folder

Comment: That's odd; it's working for me verbatim (bash 3.2 OSX). Can you post the output of `$SHELL --version`? Also, are you testing in a brand-new `git init`ed folder? If so, create a branch and commit and test again. Are you running the code while *in* a Git folder, or from somewhere else and then `cd`ing into that folder? If so, you'll need to wire it up through `PROMPT_COMMAND` to update when you change directories.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

This is not a new git inited folder

Tried with brand new folder adding a new file and commiting it and such and creating new branch and nothing

Comment: Git version? I think you'll need at least 1.8.3.

Comment: $ git --version
git version 2.15.1.windows.2

Comment: I added some more information to my question; check if that works? If not, it may (though this seems unlikely) be an issue with the Bash you're using on Windows; try it on a Linux system, or with a different Bash prompt on Windows (e.g. switch msys for WSL if you're not using it already, or the shell that comes with some Windows distributions of Git, or cygwin-installed Bash directly).

Comment: your edits did the trick.  It reports (HEAD) on a fresh init until I commit something, which I'm ok with, then it says master. and switch branches work, no new line when not in GIT folder, this works exactly as I want, thank you